# React Js + Laravel route to web or api?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am confused about how a React Js front should be "plugged" to a laravel view/route .

Does the route for React view should be placed in the /web or in the /api related file ?

Comment: React isn't really my field of expertise, so I won't answer this question. But I would highly recommend to separate your frontend from the backend in two separate projects. Your frontend would consume the API you would build with Laravel.

Comment: @IlyasDeckers this I know I need to separate it and have the front end to consume the API, the point is I see some tutorials where they use routes/web.php and other seems to use routes/api.php so I am confused which one should be used.

Comment: I always use api.php for defining my API routes. Most of the time I just delete the web.php file. This article is a good read for creating your first API: https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial.  
I would also recommend looking into Lumen, this is a framework build by the devs of laravel, but focused on building API's, without all the unnecessary features that Laravel provides for views, sessions,...

Comment: @IlyasDeckers I have already looked into lumen. Currently my need is to have a web app for our client to book service online but simultaneously I also need to have our staff and customer to be able to use a mobile app. In the same time I am considering React for the front end of the web appa and Reactnative for the mobile app. I am just confused of which route I should declare where in this case..

Answer (score 0):

Both web.php and api.php have different purposes. (Google it)

In my opinion, If your frontend is in the same app where your backend is then you can use any of them and good choice will be to use web.php (it is my personal opinion based on my experience, anyone could disagree with that.)

And if your front end is in the different project then you should utilize api.php

Hope this helps!